# Understanding Spring @Autowired usage

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-3

I am reading the spring 3.0.x reference documentation to understand Spring Autowired annotation:

[3.9.2 @Autowired and @Inject](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

I am not able to understand the below examples. Do we need to do something in the XML for it to work?

EXAMPLE 1

```
public class SimpleMovieLister {

    private MovieFinder movieFinder;

    @Autowired
    public void setMovieFinder(MovieFinder movieFinder) {
        this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
    }

    // ...
}
```

EXAMPLE 2

```
public class MovieRecommender {

    private MovieCatalog movieCatalog;

    private CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao;

    @Autowired
    public void prepare(MovieCatalog movieCatalog,
                    CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
        this.movieCatalog = movieCatalog;
        this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
    }

    // ...
}
```

How can the two classes be autowired implementing the same interface and using the same class?

Example:

```
class Red implements Color
class Blue implements Color

class myMainClass{
    @Autowired 
    private Color color;

    draw(){
        color.design(); 
    } 
}
```

Which design method will be called? How do I make sure the design method of Red class will be called and not Blue?

Answer (score 593, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The `@Autowired` annotation spares you the need to do the wiring by yourself in the XML file (or any other way) and just finds for you what needs to be injected where and does that for you.

**Full explanation**

The `@Autowired` annotation allows you to skip configurations elsewhere of what to inject and just does it for you. Assuming your package is `com.mycompany.movies` you have to put this tag in your XML (application context file):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.movies" />
```

This tag will do an auto-scanning. Assuming each class that has to become a bean is annotated with a correct annotation like `@Component` (for simple bean) or `@Controller` (for a servlet control) or `@Repository` (for `DAO` classes) and these classes are somewhere under the package `com.mycompany.movies`, Spring will find all of these and create a bean for each one. This is done in 2 scans of the classes - the first time it just searches for classes that need to become a bean and maps the injections it needs to be doing, and on the second scan it injects the beans. Of course, you can define your beans in the more traditional XML file or with an [`@Configuration`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24014919/2083523) class (or any combination of the three).

The `@Autowired` annotation tells Spring where an injection needs to occur. If you put it on a method `setMovieFinder` it understands (by the prefix `set` + the `@Autowired` annotation) that a bean needs to be injected. In the second scan, Spring searches for a bean of type `MovieFinder`, and if it finds such bean, it injects it to this method. If it finds two such beans you will get an `Exception`. To avoid the `Exception`, you can use the `@Qualifier` annotation and tell it which of the two beans to inject in the following manner:

```
@Qualifier("redBean")
class Red implements Color {
   // Class code here
}

@Qualifier("blueBean")
class Blue implements Color {
   // Class code here
}
```

Or if you prefer to declare the beans in your XML, it would look something like this:

```
<bean id="redBean" class="com.mycompany.movies.Red"/>

<bean id="blueBean" class="com.mycompany.movies.Blue"/>
```

In the `@Autowired` declaration, you need to also add the `@Qualifier` to tell which of the two color beans to inject:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("redBean")
public void setColor(Color color) {
  this.color = color;
}
```

If you don't want to use two annotations (the `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier`) you can use `@Resource` to combine these two:

```
@Resource(name="redBean")
public void setColor(Color color) {
  this.color = color;
}
```

The `@Resource` (you can read some extra data about it in the first comment on this answer) spares you the use of two annotations and instead, you only use one.

I'll just add two more comments:

1. Good practice would be to use `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired` because it is not Spring-specific and is [part of the `JSR-330` standard](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-and-jsr-330-inject-and-named-example/).
2. Another good practice would be to put the `@Inject` / `@Autowired` on a constructor instead of a method. If you put it on a constructor, you can validate that the injected beans are not null and fail fast when you try to start the application and avoid a `NullPointerException` when you need to actually use the bean.

**Update**: To complete the picture, I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24014919/2083523) about the `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Just for complete your awesome answer: '@Resource' is part of the JSR-250 standard and has extra semantics over and above simple injection (As you have said '@Autowired' is from Spring; and '@Inject' is part of the JSR-330) :)

Comment: If `MovieFinder` is a Interface, and we have a bean for `MovieFinderImpl`(bean id = movieFinder), Spring will auto inject it by type or by name?

Comment: @jaskey - it depends on whether you use `@Qualifier`. If you do - by name, if not - by type. By-type would work only if you have only one bean of type `MovieFinder` in your context. More than 1 would lead to an exception.

Comment: @Avi, Awesome answer. But I do not understand how the `@Autowired` annotation works on the `prepare` method in **Example 2**. It is initializing the `MovieRecommender` but, technically, it is **NOT** a setter.

Comment: @KaranChadha - The `@Autowired` also works for constructors. It finds the required dependencies and injects them to the constructor.

Comment: This was elaborate and has helped me to understand thanks for the answer

Comment: @Avi Would be nice if you could make the fantastic summary you gave "So, to sum it up" as a TL;DR; on top :)

Comment: @killjoy - Good idea, I did just that.

Comment: You mention you need `<context:component-scan ... />` to use @Configuration classes to define beans in this answer, but in the link to your other SO quesiton/answer, you mention you need `<context:annotation-config/>`.  Do you mind clarifying this point?

Answer (score 22):

Nothing in the example says that the "classes implementing the same interface". `MovieCatalog` is a type and `CustomerPreferenceDao` is another type. Spring can easily tell them apart.

In Spring 2.x, wiring of beans mostly happened via bean IDs or names. This is still supported by Spring 3.x but often, you will have one instance of a bean with a certain type - most services are singletons. Creating names for those is tedious. So Spring started to support "autowire by type".

What the examples show is various ways that you can use to inject beans into fields, methods and constructors.

The XML already contains all the information that Spring needs since you have to specify the fully qualified class name in each bean. You need to be a bit careful with interfaces, though:

This autowiring will fail:

```
 @Autowired
 public void prepare( Interface1 bean1, Interface1 bean2 ) { ... }
```

Since Java doesn't keep the parameter names in the byte code, Spring can't distinguish between the two beans anymore. The fix is to use `@Qualifier`:

```
 @Autowired
 public void prepare( @Qualifier("bean1") Interface1 bean1,
     @Qualifier("bean2")  Interface1 bean2 ) { ... }
```

Comment: @AaronDigulla That was nice. However I want to know how do you call the function `prepare`, which parameters will be used to call this function ?

Comment: @NguyenQuangAnh I'm not calling the method, Spring will do it when the bean is created. This happens exactly when `@Autowired` fields are injected. Spring will then see that parameters are needed and it will use the same rules used for field injection to find the parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can configure the Spring servlet context xml file to define your beans (i.e., classes), so that it can do the automatic injection for you.  However, do note, that you have to do other configurations to have Spring up and running and the best way to do that, is to follow a tutorial ground up.

Once you have your Spring configured probably, you can do the following in your Spring servlet context xml file for Example 1 above to work (please *replace* the package name of **com.movies** to what the true package name is and if this is a 3rd party class, then be sure that the appropriate jar file is on the classpath) :

```
<beans:bean id="movieFinder" class="com.movies.MovieFinder" />
```

or if the MovieFinder class has a constructor with a primitive value, then you could something like this,

```
<beans:bean id="movieFinder" class="com.movies.MovieFinder" >
    <beans:constructor-arg value="100" />
</beans:bean>
```

or if the MovieFinder class has a constructor expecting another class, then you could do something like this,

```
<beans:bean id="movieFinder" class="com.movies.MovieFinder" >
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="otherBeanRef" />
</beans:bean>
```

...where '*otherBeanRef*' is another bean that has a reference to the expected class.

Comment: Defining all the wiring in the XML just misses the whole idea of `@Autowired`