# How do I post-process beans of @Configuration classes that define more @Beans in JavaConfig?

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

In Spring XML, I can define a bean that instantiates a class annotated with @Configuration.  When I do, that bean is post-processed.  Any methods inside that class with @Bean are also added to the container.  How do I perform a similar post-processing in JavaConfig?

Here's the XML version:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.so.Test">
    <property name="prop" value="set before instantiating @Beans defined in Test"/>
</bean>
```

The associated Test class:

```
@Configuration
class Test {
    private String prop;

    void setProp(final String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    @Bean
    NeedThisBean needThisBeanToo() {
        return new NeedThisBean(prop);
    }
}
```

If I use Spring XML Config, both `test` and `needThisBeanToo` are available in the container.  `needThisBeanToo` is added via a BeanPostProcessor, though I can't recall which one.  If I use JavaConfig, only `test` is available in the container.  How do I make `needThisBeanToo` available to the container?  `@Import` would work, **except** that `prop` being set is required for `needThisBeanToo` to be initialized correctly.

The part that makes all of this complicated is that `Test` is vended from a library I'm consuming.  I don't control `Test`, nor can I change it.  If I drive it from JavaConfig, it would look like this:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    Test test() {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setProp("needed to init `needThisBeanToo` and others");
        return test;
    }
}
```

The JavaConfig example **does not** instantiate `needThisBeanToo` despite it being defined in `Test`.  I need to get `needThisBeanToo` defined, preferably without doing it myself, since I don't want to copy code I don't own.  Delegation isn't attractive, since there are a number of subsequent annotations/scopes defined on `needThisBeanToo` (and others defined inside `Test`).

Comment: I would very much like to help you but I don't really understand your problem from the way you explained. What is it that you're missing exactly? The property? Anyway - I can point you to a question and answer of mine that explains in details everything you need to know for converting XML to @Configuration class: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24014919/2083523

If this still doesn't help, please try to explain what exactly you're missing and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Edited, let me know if it clarifies.

Comment: DId my answer help? Or was it something else you're looking for?

Comment: Oh, I think I got you now. Do you mean that there is no bean of type `NeedThisBean` loaded to the spring container?

Comment: Correct.  I added the JavaConfig-driven approach as well to help explain.  JavaConfig doesn't "recursively" look for @Beans, and I need to do that.

Comment: Are you importing the @Configuration class? Do you have a root spring configuration XML or don't you have XMLs at all? It's important to understand where the root spring context is loaded from.

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem - answer is on the way.

Comment: Have a look at my answer now. I think that's what you need. Hope I explained the problem clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is is that you're **ignoring** the `@Configuration` annotation completely. Why is that?

When code reaches this line `Test test = new Test();` it just doesn't do anything with `@Configuration`. Why? Because annotation is not something that a constructor is aware of. Annotation only marks some meta-data for the class. When spring loads classes it searches for annotations, when you call a constructor of a class, you don't. So the `@Configuration` is just ignored because you instantiate `Test` with `new Test()` and not through spring.

What you need to do is to import `Test` as a spring bean. Either via XML as you showed in your question OR using `@Import`. You problem with `prop` is that the setter isn't called because that's just not the way to do it. What you need to be doing is either do something like that:

```
@Configuration
class Test {
  private String prop = "set before instantiating @Beans defined in Test";

  @Bean
  NeedThisBean needThisBeanToo() {
      return new NeedThisBean(prop);
  }
}
```

Or to create a property in spring (this is a different subject) and inject the value:

```
@Configuration
class Test {
  @Autowired
  @Value("${some.property.to.inject}") // You can also use SPeL syntax with #{... expression ...}
  private String prop;

  @Bean
  NeedThisBean needThisBeanToo() {
      return new NeedThisBean(prop);
  }
}
```

You can also create a bean of type `String` and inject it as follows:

```
@Configuration
class Test {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifer("nameOfBeanToInject")
  private String prop;

  @Bean
  NeedThisBean needThisBeanToo() {
      return new NeedThisBean(prop);
  }
}
```

In the last case you can define your original `MyConfiguration` with this bean:

```
@Configuration
@Import(Test.class)
class MyConfiguration
{
    @Bean(name = "nameOfBeanToInject")
    String test() {
        return "needed to init `needThisBeanToo` and others";
    }
}
```

In any case you have to import `Test` either using `@Import` or as a normal XML bean. It won't work by calling the constructor explicitly.

Comment: I don't think I'm ignoring the annotation.  When I use XML, I don't do anything with the annotation.  Spring is handling the annotation when it's defined in XML, but that's separate from calling the constructor.  What I want is for Spring to handle the annotation once the @Bean method (which includes the `new Test()` call) returns.

Comment: It just doesn't work that way. When you call `new Test()` the annotation is ignored. When you do it via a spring XML, spring handles the instantiation of the object and thus before creating the new bean, it searches for annotations of interest to it.

Comment: Want an easy way to understand better what I'm saying - run your code in debug and check the spring container for the `test` bean when you define it with XML and when you define it the way you showed in your example. You'll see that in one case it's just a plain `Test` object and in the second it will be a spring object (not of type `Test`. I don't remember the exact type but it's easy to debug). You would see that the latter contains `Test` as an inner property but it's not of type `Test`

Comment: Anyway, try the last example I gave, I think it's the most straight-forward one for doing what you're trying to accomplish without defining a property interpretation infra.

Comment: I'm definitely familiar with what's created.  I've been through the debugger step-by-step.  XML does some post-processing, JavaConfig doesn't.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to have JavaConfig do the same post-processing as the XML approach does.  If I could setter-inject the `Test` created by @Import (in your last example) prior to Spring reading all the @Beans it contains, I think that would work.  Is that possible?

Comment: I have to admit I haven't tried but it might cause some problematic loop. I'm not sure though. Anyway, that's not the way to do it. You should define `@Configuration` bean as beans that are not used by the application. If you find yourself in need to inject a `@Configuration` class, it means your doing something the wrong way. If `Test` is an application bean (a bean that is used by your business logic) don't make it also a `@Configuration` bean.

Comment: The @Configuration bean "Test" is **not** used by my application.  It is vended by a library I need, but cannot control.  That's **the only way** (without significant copy/paste, essentially forcing me to maintain a fork) I can configure the library.  `@Import` on Test **does not** let me configure it.  From your examples: 1) doesn't work, I can't change Test, 2) same reason, 3) same reason, and 4) won't work because I can't get the property into Test.  I'm not claiming this library vended its configuration correctly, but it's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to handle vended @Configuration classes that require some properties to be set prior to creating their @Beans:

Vended @Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
class Test {

    private String property;

    public setProperty(final String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    @Bean
    PropertyUser propertyUser() {
        return new PropertyUser(property);
    }

    @Bean
    SomeBean someBean() {
        // other instantiation logic
        return new SomeBeanImpl();
    }
}
```

Here's the consuming @Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    static String myProperty() {
        // Create myProperty
    }

    /**
     * Extending Test allows Spring JavaConfig to create
     * the beans provided by Test.  Declaring
     * Test as a @Bean does not provide the @Beans defined
     * within it.
     */
    @Configuration
    static class ModifiedTest extends Test {

        ModifiedTest() {
            this.setProperty(myProperty());
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        SomeBean someBean() {
            return new SomeBeanCustomImpl(this.propertyUser());
    }
}
```

Comment: It feels like you're trying to force it. That's not how it meant to be used and you're creating spaghetti configuration. That's fine of course if your goal is just to use the setter, but there are ways to do what you wanted in a much simpler way. If you would like to understand how to do it, I'd love to explain my answer a bit further. I just love clean code and hate to see you doing something that is so complexed to achieve something so simple.

Comment: @Avi, you haven't given me a way that actually works, yet.  See my comment on your answer.  To be clear, I don't like my solution.  I agree that clean code is better, and I wish there was a simpler way.  It isn't my goal to use the setter, it's just **the only way I have to configure** the `VendedConfiguration` class.  I don't own `VendedConfiguration`; I can't change `VendedConfiguration`.  It was designed to be used via Spring XML, and I'd prefer not to use Spring XML.  Unfortunately, `VendedConfiguration` does quite a bit of self-referencing of its `@Beans`, and `property` controls it all.

Comment: Given all that, I think you're right, I am forcing it.  I disagree with the 'spaghetti configuration' because it's all encapsulated in a single @Configuration class I own, and therefore isn't spread across lots of configuration.

Comment: I think that either I haven't understand your question right, which is then why my answer doesn't help or the other way around. Because the way I understood your question, you should be able to use my solution. You haven't mentioned `VendedConfiguration` in the original question so that may be the reason why. Also, you haven't mentioned that you can't change it which is a very critical factor for your question and of course I would have either offer a different solution or not answering at all if I knew this.

Comment: I apologize for the name change.  Consider `Test` == `VendedConfiguration` (I've fixed that).  From the initial question: "I don't control Test, nor can I change it."

Comment: Ok, have to admit I missed this line. I'll try to think if I have a still better idea to solve this

Comment: Now I understand why you have need for this complex solution and still you can do something else that would be clearer. I'll edit my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Actually I would it mostly the same but you don't need the inner class, you can still extract `ModifiedTest` to an independent class and use `@Inject` or `@Autowired` to inject the parameters bean to the constructor.