# unable converting messy spring-security-xml to Java based config

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

After upgrading some dependencies in our maven project to make the project run with jdk11 containers, I had to update from SpringSecurity 4.0.x to 4.2.x. So I wanted to give it a shot and convert the messy XML to a proper Java-config.

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd" default-autowire="byName">



    <!-- Spring Security Settings -->
    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>
    <security:http-firewall ref="defaultHttpFirewall"/>

    <security:http pattern="/api/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/prometheus/**" security="none" />

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/login*">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="managerRequestRedirectFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/login/sso*">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/sso*"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="managerRequestRedirectFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/authenticate" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/resources/bootstrap/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/resources/css/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/resources/js/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp*" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/databaseStatus" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/module/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/myarea/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/ajax/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/logout/sso" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/download/**" security="none" />


    <bean id="managerRequestRedirectFilter" class="com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerRequestRedirectFilter"/>

    <!-- Spring Security Kerberos Settings -->

    <bean id="authenticationResultFilter" class="com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerAuthenticationResultFilter"/>



    <!-- rest -->

    <bean id="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class=" com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter" />    
    <bean id="restEntryPoint" class="com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/rest/**">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/hooks/**">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/hooks/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/get/**">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/get/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/hook/**">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/hook/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/hookhistories/**">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/hookhistories/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/hookcalls/**">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/hookcalls/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint" pattern="/hookversions/**">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/hookversions/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="restAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <!--  -->

    <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" /> 

    <bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
        <property name="errorPage" value="/login"/>
    </bean>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="spnegoEntryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="managerRequestRedirectFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationResultFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>



    <bean id="spnegoEntryPoint" class="com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <bean id="spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="failureHandler" ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
        <property name="successHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="kerberosAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="kerberosAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="kerberosClient">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosClient">
                <property name="debug" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="kerberosUserDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="ticketValidator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator">
                <property name="servicePrincipal"
                                    value="HTTP/an.URL"/>
                <property name="keyTabLocation"
                                    value="file:/etc/krb5.keytab"/>
                <property name="debug" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="kerberosUserDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig">
        <property name="debug" value="false" />
        <property name="krbConfLocation" value="/etc/krb5.conf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="kerberosUserDetailsService" class="com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.KerberosUserDetailsService"/>  


</beans>
```

and the try of a config I used:

```java
package com.pany.managertemplate.configuration.service;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosClient;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.HttpFirewall;

import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.KerberosUserDetailsService;
import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerAuthenticationResultFilter;
import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerRequestRedirectFilter;
import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.ManagerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.pany.managertemplate.authentication.service.RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class GlobalSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationResultFilter")
        private ManagerAuthenticationResultFilter authenticationResultFilter;

        @Autowired
        private KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        private KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        private ManagerRequestRedirectFilter managerRequestRedirectFilter;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("restEntryPoint")
        private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("spnegoEntryPoint")
        private ManagerAuthenticationEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint;

        @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
        {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception
        {
            authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider);
            authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.kerberosAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/bootstrap/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/css/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/js/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp*").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/databaseStatus").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/module/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/myarea/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ajax/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/logout/sso").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/download/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/prometheus/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER");
            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.spnegoEntryPoint);
            http.addFilterBefore(this.managerRequestRedirectFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.addFilterAt(this.spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.addFilterAfter(this.managerRequestRedirectFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class LoginSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Autowired
        private KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        private KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        private ManagerRequestRedirectFilter managerRequestRedirectFilter;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("restEntryPoint")
        private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception
        {
            authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider);
            authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.kerberosAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.antMatcher("/login*").antMatcher("/login/sso*");
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.restEntryPoint);
            http.addFilterBefore(this.managerRequestRedirectFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login");
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class RestSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationResultFilter")
        private ManagerAuthenticationResultFilter authenticationResultFilter;

        @Autowired
        private KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        private KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        private RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter restAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("restEntryPoint")
        private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception
        {
            authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider);
            authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.kerberosAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.antMatcher("/rest/**").antMatcher("/hooks/**").antMatcher("/get/**").antMatcher("/hook/**").antMatcher("/hookhistories/**")
                    .antMatcher("/hookcalls/**").antMatcher("/hookversions/**");
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.restEntryPoint);
            http.addFilterAt(this.restAuthenticationProcessingFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.addFilterAfter(this.authenticationResultFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationResultFilter")
    private ManagerAuthenticationResultFilter authenticationResultFilter;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restEntryPoint")
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("spnegoEntryPoint")
    private ManagerAuthenticationEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandler()
    {
        AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandlerImpl = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
        accessDeniedHandlerImpl.setErrorPage("/login");
        return accessDeniedHandlerImpl;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        // though StrictHttpFirewall is advised
        super.configure(web);
        web.httpFirewall(this.defaultHttpFirewall());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall defaultHttpFirewall()
    {
        DefaultHttpFirewall firewall = new DefaultHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }

    @Bean
    public GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig()
    {
        GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig = new GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig();
        globalSunJaasKerberosConfig.setDebug(false);
        globalSunJaasKerberosConfig.setKrbConfLocation("/etc/krb5.conf");
        return globalSunJaasKerberosConfig;
    }

    @Bean("kerberosAuthenticationProvider")
    public KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider(@Qualifier("kerberosClient") final SunJaasKerberosClient kerberosClient,
            final KerberosUserDetailsService kerberosUserDetailsService)
    {
        KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider = new KerberosAuthenticationProvider();
        kerberosAuthenticationProvider.setKerberosClient(kerberosClient);
        kerberosAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(kerberosUserDetailsService);
        return kerberosAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean("kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider")
    public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider(final KerberosUserDetailsService kerberosUserDetailsService,
            @Qualifier("ticketValidator") final SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ticketValidator)
    {
        KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
        kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(kerberosUserDetailsService);
        kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(ticketValidator);
        return kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosUserDetailsService kerberosUserDetailsService()
    {
        return new KerberosUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean("spnegoEntryPoint")
    public ManagerAuthenticationEntryPoint managerAuthenticationEntryPoint()
    {
        return new ManagerAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean("authenticationResultFilter")
    public ManagerAuthenticationResultFilter managerAuthenticationResultFilter()
    {
        return new ManagerAuthenticationResultFilter();
    }

    @Bean("authenticationSuccessHandler")
    public ManagerAuthenticationSuccessHandler managerAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
    {
        return new ManagerAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public ManagerRequestRedirectFilter managerRequestRedirectFilter()
    {
        return new ManagerRequestRedirectFilter();
    }

    @Bean("spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter")
    public ManagerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter managerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
            final SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler,
            @Qualifier("authenticationSuccessHandler") final AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler)
    {
        ManagerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter managerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter = new ManagerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        managerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        managerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setFailureHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler);
        managerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        return managerSpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean("restEntryPoint")
    public RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint()
    {
        return new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter restAuthenticationProcessingFilter()
    {
        return new RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
    }

    @Bean("simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler")
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler()
    {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.setUseForward(true);
        simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login");
        return simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SunJaasKerberosClient sunJaasKerberosClient()
    {
        SunJaasKerberosClient sunJaasKerberosClient = new SunJaasKerberosClient();
        sunJaasKerberosClient.setDebug(false);
        return sunJaasKerberosClient;
    }

    @Bean("ticketValidator")
    public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
        sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.setServicePrincipal("HTTP/an.URL");
        Resource keyTabFile = new UrlResource("file:/etc/krb5.keytab");
        sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.setKeyTabLocation(keyTabFile);
        sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.setDebug(false);
        return sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator;
    }
}
```

Login via /login works fine, permissions working inside the applications webinterface.
The problem I encountered is the part for the server-to-server communication via REST.
Sending the proper credentials like used to now just returns the login page instead of the requested resource - this is the point where I am stuck.
I feel like, the config is too complex and confusing at some points because of several entrypoints. but that was what I read in the offical documentation. Or is there an easier way and I am just thinking too complex? In short Java-Config behaves not like the Java-Config, and I can't see why so far.

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014919/understanding-spring-configuration-class

Comment: I know how the single parts work and are translated - but the whole artwork does not want to form properly