# @Autowired Foo foo, if Foo is not a @Component

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I would like to auto-wire foo:

```
@Autowired
Foo foo
```

but I cannot modify class `Foo` and mark it as `@Component`. What is the cleanest way to autowire foo?

BTW, I would prefer to use Java Spring configuration instead of XML config if you need to use config to address this problem.

**Related:**

- [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)

Answer (score 4):

The @Bean annotation seems to be what you're after...

In your Javaconfig class you would create an @Bean annotated method returning Foo:

```
@Bean
public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}
```

See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `xml` configuration file to create a bean of the class `Foo`. Then `@Autowired` works the same as annotating the beans directions.

Sample `xml` file:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="foo" class="Foo"/>
</beans>
```

If you now include this into your file with the autoscan then this bean is used as if it were annotated with `@Component`.