# Spring Data JPA | Dynamic runtime multiple database connection

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jboss5.x

**Use Case:**

During JBoss server startup, one permanent database connection is already made using **Spring Data JPA** configurations(xml based approach).

Now when application is already up and running, requirement is to connect to multiple Database and connection string is dynamic which is available on run-time.

How to achieve this using **Spring Data JPA**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to switch out your data source is to define a "runtime" repository that is configured with the "runtime" data source.  But this will make client code aware of the different repos:

```
package com...runtime.repository;

public interface RuntimeRepo extends JpaRepository<OBJECT, ID> { ... }

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    transactionManagerRef="runtimeTransactionManager", 
    entityManagerFactoryRef="runtimeEmfBean")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RuntimeDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean public DataSource runtimeDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource rds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        // setup driver, username, password, url
        return rds;
    }

    @Bean public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean runtimeEmfBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(runtimeDataSource());
        // setup JpaVendorAdapter, jpaProperties, 
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean public PlatformTransactionManager runtimeTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jtm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jtm.setEntityManagerFactory(runtimeEmfBean());
        return jtm;
    }
}
```

I have combined the code to save space; you would define the javaconfig and the repo interface in separate files, but within the same package.

To make client code agnostic of the repo type, **implement your own repo factory**, autowire the repo factory into client code and have your repo factory check application state before returning the particular repo implementation.

Comment: We already have an existing xml based approach implemented in the application. When we try to integrate the above mentioned solution in the application, we get the following exception;

No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

where in one EntityManagerFactory would be the one configured in our xml and other being the newly configured according to your solution.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried autowiring by name instead of by type?  See [understanding-spring-autowired-usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)