# Spring : Autowired bean is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, autowired

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am autowiring a field, but it is getting set as NULL. I checked the solutions on net for the same problem, as they describe, I should not create a new instance of classes when working, rather get it from spring. I tried that as well, but it always complains the resource is not found.

Here is the class :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GoogleAuthorization{

    @Autowired
    private DriveQuickstart driveQuickstart;  // This guy is null

    public void saveCredentials(final String authCode) throws IOException {

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(authCode).setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).execute();
        Credential credential = flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
        System.out.println(" Credential access token is "+credential.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("Credential refresh token is "+credential.getRefreshToken());
// It fails at below point.
        this.driveQuickstart.storeCredentials(credential);
    }
```

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getgooglelogin")
    public String getGoogleLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session,Model model) {

       /* ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml");
        GoogleAuthorization helper = (GoogleAuthorization) applicationContext.getBean("helper");*/
        GoogleAuthorization helper = new GoogleAuthorization();
}
```

I tried getting it via the root-context.xml as you can see above, but no matter what path I would put, it could not find it.

DriveQuickStartImpl :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DriveQuickstartImpl implements DriveQuickstart{
// All these below guys work just fine. 
@Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    private GoogleDriveService googleDriveService;

    @Autowired
    private GroupAttachmentsService groupAttachmentsService;

    @Autowired
    private GroupAccountService groupAccountService;
}
```

What am I doing wrong. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

*Update*

Image for where root-context.xml belongs :

[image]

Comment: Do you use component scan? Otherwise, you have to explicitly tell spring what should be injected and where. Have a look at my explanation about `@Autowired` in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19419296/2083523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just autowire the GoogleAuthorization helper (you can do this as you are already in a Spring-managed controller):

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DriveQuickstartImpl implements DriveQuickstart{

    // Other stuff...

    @Autowired 
    private GoogleAuthorization helper;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/getgooglelogin")
public String getGoogleLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session,Model model) {

       // use "helper"
}
```

If you autowire the helper, it is injected and managed by Spring. So Spring will build and autowire it correctly.

Comment: Please note, I am using the constructor and from there I am calling methods directly, or should I just use an interface?

Comment: Which constructor do you mean?

Comment: This worked, I was marking it as private in an abstract Controller class where all my autowired fields are, that was my mistake... Sooooo embarrassing.. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
 GoogleAuthorization helper = new GoogleAuthorization();
```

As you created with `GoogleAuthorization`  with `new`, `Spring` container wont be aware of the class which we might think as a spring bean and as a result  it fails to `Autowire` it. Make sure your class in which `@Autowiring` is done is a spring bean. Trying instantiating `GoogleAuthorization` using [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) as :

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml");

GoogleAuthorization helper = (GoogleAuthorization)applicationContext.getBean("helper");
```

Comment: Where do I get the applicationContext from? Did you see the Controller code I had posted, I tried the same by searching the XML file, but XML file was not found no matter what path I used.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [root-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

Comment: I will update the main post with screenshot for project structure.

Comment: Its solved, I injected the bean in Controller itself.

Comment: Great, I am about to ask you question why you are trying to read the configuration file from `Classpath` in Web Application because normally it's a way to use in standalone application.

Answer (score 1):

if you create an instance with `'new'` on your own there will be no spring wiring at all.

if you use Spring in a Web-App Context you could use the [ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/) to initialize your Spring-Context.

```
    <!-- inside WEB-INF/web.xml -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <!-- path to your Spring context configuration-->
        <!-- for example -->
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-webapp-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

you can then inject the GoogleAuthorization Bean in your controller as well, so there is no need to get hold of the application context to do a 'lookup' ... if you use spring try to let spring do the wiring instead of relying on 'lookups'.

Comment: I did the same, injected the bean in Controller.