# Is there a reason that we give spring annotation a name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I noticed when using annotation for spring or spring mvc, some programmers give the annotation a name along with it. For example:

```
@Repository("customerRepository")
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository{
}
```

I believe the class functioning the same without giving the `@Repository` a name. Would there be a situation that name the annotation useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is mainly meant for solving ambiguity when performing an auto-scan and using [`@Autowired`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419296/2083523). I gave a thorough answer explaining about `@Autowired` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419296/2083523) which also explains about the need to name the beans.

Let's assume we have 2 classes that implement `CustomerRepository`:

```
@Repository
public class MyCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {
}

@Repository
public class OtherCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {
}
```

Let's now assume we have a class that uses `@Autowired` to inject a `CustomerRepository`:

```
public class SomeClass {
  @Autowired
  private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
}
```

When performing an auto-scan, you need to have a way to differentiate between them. Otherwise Spring would throw an exception saying that it can't tell which of the beans should be injected.

So we can now add a logical name to each implementation:

```
@Repository("myRepository")
public class MyCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {
}

@Repository("otherRepository")
public class OtherCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {
}
```

And now you can help Spring solve the ambiguity as follows:

```
public class SomeClass {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myRepository")
  private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to convert the entity into a Spring bean, if autodetected.

From the official doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html):-

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, 
>   to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

Answer (score 0):

The [AnnotationBeanNameGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html) is responsible for picking a name for your beans. If you specify a name you can use a different convention for your bean names than what would otherwise be generated based on the class name.

Auto-generated bean names are not fool proof; two classes with the same name can cause a duplicate bean definition, as can two classes inheriting the same interface.

The use of explicit names also ensures that code refactoring does not implicitly break the bean wiring.