# Differ which repository object will be injected to reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm just learning Spring for about 2 weeks now and try to understand a Repository concept, so I'm still unfamiliar with many terms, but I'll try my best to explain , assuming I have class :

Product.java

```
  class Product {
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Interface ProductRepository.java

```
public interface ProductRepository {
    public List<Product> getAllProducts();
}
```

InMemoryProductRepository.java

```
@Repository
class InMemoryProductRepository implements ProductRepository{
....
....
}
```

productController.java

```
class productController{

  @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


 @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String list(Model model) {


        model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.getAllProducts());
        return "products";

    }

}
```

In my productController is what i'm talking about,

`productRepository` is not directly implemented to specific object like  `productRepository = new InMemoryProductRepository ();` , instead of the `productRepository` is marked with `@Autowired` and because `InMemoryProductRepository`  has  `@Repository` so `InMemoryProductRepository`   will be injected to this `productRepository` reference , but my question is if there is another class who implements this `ProductRepository`  interface and marked with `@Repository`  also :
assuming like

InMemoryProductRepository2.java

```
@Repository
        class InMemoryProductRepository2 implements ProductRepository{
        ....
       ....
    }
```

then which one of those two objects will be injected to

```
@Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
```

? How do I differ them?

Thanks , sorry for my language.

Comment: You want to use `@Qualifier` when injecting your repository.  Take a look at the answer here, it might help you out with the autowiring concept: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19419296/1458983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was such scenario, you would give name to each of your implementing bean @Repository("name") and use @Qualifier("name") annotation with @Autowired.