# How to do inheritance in Dao layer?

Tags: spring

I am working with SpringMVC+Hibernate, I want to apply Inheritance in DAO layer, I am doing like below:

**BaseDao.java**

```java
public interface BaseDao
{
   public Serializable save(Object object) throws DataAccessException,
        HibernateException;

public void merge(Object object) throws DataAccessException,
        HibernateException;

public void flush() throws DataAccessException,HibernateException;
 }
```

**EmpDao.java**

```java
 public interface EmpDao extends BaseDao{
 }
```

**BaseDaoImpl.java**

```java
@Repository
public class BaseDaoImpl implements BaseDao{
 // Implementation for baseDao methods 
}
```

**EmpDaoImpl .java**

```java
 @Repository
public class EmpDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl implements EmpDao{
 // Implementation
}
```

But I am getting below error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
[BaseDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show entire stacktrace?

Comment: Do you really need instance of `BaseDaoImpl` as a standalone bean? If not, just remove the `@Repository` annotation from it and mark the `BaseDaoImpl` class as `abstract` (optional, but good practice). It will then be enough to have `@Repository` annotation on concrete Dao implementations (e.g. `EmpDaoImpl`).

Comment: Dont you think you need @Qualifier?

Comment: @Soujanya you are using spring data, why don't you use `JpaRepository` interface instead and if you need to customize it - you can extend `SimpleJpaRepository` class, if you don't need to customize ( add new methods ) - then you don't need the implementation class, an interface with `@Repository` annotation is enough, Spring creates the class in runtime

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have both `BaseDaoImpl` and `EmpDaoImpl` as two beans in your Spring container, you need to tell Spring which one to use wherever you have an `@Autowired` field of type `BaseDao` using [`@Qualifier` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s11.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers).

Related: [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to inject `BaseDao` and Spring is complaining there are two candidates.

I think this is actually a design problem. You wanted to use `BaseDaoImpl` both as a concrete bean that you use directly and also as a base class for other DAOs. This is bad because the sub-classes does not actually *extend* but simply *uses* their parent class. The better pattern would be to get rid of the `extends` and simply inject the `BaseDaoImpl` into the other DAOs.

Also, the interfaces looks superfluous. If you're working around the proxy problem, just use `proxyTargetClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic types like this

**BaseDao.java**

```
public interface BaseDao<EntityType extends Object>
{
   public Serializable save(EntityType entity) throws DataAccessException,
        HibernateException;

   public void merge(EntityType entity) throws DataAccessException,
        HibernateException;

   public void flush() throws DataAccessException,HibernateException;
}
```

**BaseDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<EntityType extends Object> implements BaseDao<EntityType>{
 // Implementation for baseDao methods 
}
```

**EmpDao.java**

```
 public interface EmpDao extends BaseDao<Employee>{
 }
```

**EmpDaoImpl .java**

```
 @Repository
public class EmpDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Employee> implements EmpDao{
 // Implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `@NoRepositoryBean` on the `BaseDao` interface so spring would not create a bean for it, as well as for `EmpDao` I assume

Comment: `@NoRepositoryBean` is a Spring Data annotation. I don't see any indication in the question that OP uses Spring Data, so it would probably be of no use here.

Comment: As well as `@Repository` bean is from Spring Data, which is being used. On the other hand - `@Qualifier` always helps to specify the exact bean name.

Comment: `@Repository` is not from Spring Data. It is a core stereotype annotation included for instance in `spring-context` dependency.