# How to access contents of an object?

Tags: object, autowired

I have autowired a class as `@Autowired(required=true) private CookieDao ewp;`

I am trying to use the `ewp` to call a function `ewp.getCookieEntry(id, name );`

How do I access the contents of `ewp`. Since it is a object I get classname@hashcode but after `.toString()` , I just get the classname.

If ewp is autowired, then is it the same as `CookieDao ewp = new CookieDao();`? If not, then what is it called and how can I extract it's values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you need to annotate your CookieDao with @Repository to the autowired work just fine, for more information have a looks into this answer : [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)