# How do I autowire an instance of a java class?

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a class that starts like this:

```
import javax.mail.Session;
//... more imports

@Component("eMailUtility")
public class MailUtility {

  @Autowired
  Session mailSession;
  //...
}
```

My IDE tells me "Could not autowire. No beans of 'Session' type found."

This message doesn't surprise me, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Session is a final class with factory methods but no public constructors. I can easily instantiate a Session somewhere, but I don't know what I need to do to make it recognizable as a target of an autowired injection. All the examples I've found on the internet show how to autowire an instance of a class that I wrote, which doesn't help me here.

(A detailed explanation of exactly how autowire works, which doesn't gloss over anything, would be very helpful, but I can't seem to find one. If you know of a good link, that would be helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create a method in a class that is annotated with `@Configuration` that returns a Session object and annotate that method with `@Bean`. In your case something like this:

```
@Bean
public Session session() {
    return <instance>;
}
```

If it was one of your own classes you could also annotate it with `@Component`, or other annotations that are itself annotated with `@Component`. Spring would then find the class with this annotation and automatically create the bean for you.

For an explanation about `@Autowired` you can look at this answer: [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)

Comment: You should also have a @ComponentScan annotation in your application (your main class, if possible) with a base_packages attribute that specifies the package of this class.