# How to get ResponseBody of @RestController as object in a MockMvc junit test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I have a simple junit test that verifies the response of a servlet endpoint.

Problem: I want to obtain the response as *java object* `Person`, and not as string/json/xml representation.

Is that possible?

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @GetMapping("/person")
    public PersonRsp getPerson(int id) {
        //...
        return rsp;
    }   
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = PersonController.class)
public class PersonControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MvcResult rt = mvc.perform(get("/person")
                .param("id", "123")
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        //TODO how to cast the result to (Person) p?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

you could deserialize it like this:

```
String json = rt.getResponse().getContentAsString();
Person person = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Person.class);
```

You can also @Autowire the ObjectMapper

Comment: Additionally can verify the response object JSON directly with `.andExpect(content().json("{'message':'ok'}"));`  etc.

Comment: How can I `@Autowire the ObjectMapper`? Can you give an example?

Comment: You can read about Autowiring [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419296/8371162) hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

As my goal was mainly to test the whole setup, means by spring autoconfigured set of objectmapper and restcontroller, I just created a mock for the endpoint. And there returned the input parameter as response, so I can validate it:

```
@RestController
public class PersonControllerMock {
    @GetMapping("/person")
    public PersonDTO getPerson(PersonDTO dto) {
        return dto;
    }   
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = PersonControllerMock.class)
public class PersonControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        mvc.perform(get("/person")
                .param("id", "123")
                .param("firstname", "john")
                .param("lastname", "doe")
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstname").value("john"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastname").value("doe"))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can use `TestRestTemplate::getForEntity` if you are not limited with `mockMvc`