# Spring Bean and Autowire to datasource

Tags: spring, servlets, javabeans, code-injection, autowired

Noob to Spring. I have 2 files: 
    foo-servlet.xml which has the following statement:

```
    <bean id:"DAO" class="a.b.data.MyDAO"/>
```

fooController.java has the following:

```
@Controller
public class FooController{
    @Autowired
    private FooDAO fooDAO;

    public void setFooDAO (FooDAO fooDAO){ this.fooDAO = fooDAO;}
```

My question: Is Spring actually replacing / injecting the definition of DAO in the servlet into my FooDAO?  I'm trying to understand the 'tie-in' between the bean and how Spring know to substitute that file for my FooDAO in the controller.

Oh, and there is no mention of @Repository or @Component anywhere in this example code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML looks kind of corrupted. I think it needs to be id=DAO
As far as i know: Autowiring is either done via the type or the name and the type. 
So when MyDAO implements FooDao your bean will be considered for Autowiring. 
But this is just a guess. The code of the Daos and the rest of the configuration would be helpful to give a correct answer to this question.
[Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)
This might answer your question as well.