# What exactly does @autowired do in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Take the following as an example

```
 public class xyz(){
    @Autowired
    private BasicConfiguration configuration;

    @RequestMapping("/dynamic-configuration")
    public Map dynamicConfiguration() {
        // Not the best practice to use a map to store differnt types!
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("message", configuration.getMessage());
        map.put("number", configuration.getNumber());
        map.put("key", configuration.isValue());
        return map;
    }
}
```

Every documentation i read says that it injects `dependecies`, however i dont understand what that means. As far as i understand, `Spring` creates a `JavaBean` of the `class xyz` and a `javabean` is a basically a standard for classes. If so, what use has the`@autowire` here?. Doesn't `xyz` have the same object `"configuration"` whether I annotate it or not?.

Comment: No, it doesnt. It has a member field that by default points to null, meaning you have no instance of ``BasicConfiguration`` to work with. Dependency Injection provides you with an instance.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19414734/476716)