# How to write embedded class query for filtering

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to filter `motherName` and `sisterName` but I don't know how to write a filter for embedded class. Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Family1 class

```java
@Entity
public class Family1 {
    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Embedded
    private FamilyNames familyNames;
    
    @Column(nullable=false,name="familyMemebers")
    private int familyMembers;
    
    @Column(nullable=false,name="contactNo")
    private long contactNo;
    
    @Embedded
    @Column(nullable=false, name="Address" )
    private Address address;
    
    public Family1() {}
        
       // getters,setters
```

FamilyNames class

```java
@Embeddable
public class FamilyNames {
    private String yourName;
    private String fatherName;
    private String motherName;
    private String sisterName;

    public FamilyNames() {}

    //getters, setters
```

Family1Controller class

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/family1")
public class Family1Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private Family1Service family1Service; 

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/fam1")
    public List<Family1> listOfDetails(@RequestParam("keyword") String keyWord){
        return family1Service.listOfDetails(keyWord);
    }
}
```

Family1Service class

```java
@Service
public class Family1Service {
    
    @Autowired
    private Family1Repository familyRepository;
    
    public List<Family1> listOfDetails(String keyWord) {
       return familyRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Family1Repository class:

```java
@Repository
public interface Family1Repository extends JpaRepository<Family1,Integer>  {

   @Query("Select f from family1 f where f.familyNames.motherName LIKE %?1%"
        + "OR f.familyNames.sisterName %?1%")
    List<Family1> findAll(String keyWord);
}
```

please help me which way to filter particular name in embedded class using query annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following query:

```java
@Query(
  "select f from Family1 f where f.familyNames.motherName LIKE '%' || :name || '%'"
    +" OR f.familyNames.sisterName LIKE '%' || :name || '%'")
List<Family1> findAll(@Param("name") String keyWord);
```

Comment: It will throw an error like this.1. Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'family1Controller' method. 2.There is already the 'family1Controller' bean method. How can I overcome the issue? Do you have any suggestion

Comment: I do not see how these errors related to the query.

Comment: I changed value="/fam1" to value=" " it will normally now

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356927/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-spring-boot-rest-controller).

Comment: I have another doubt if I give request param in the localhost:8082/family1?keyWord=xxx  it will not show only xxx related details it will show the entire details of the list. can you please tell me what mistake I made?