# Nullpoint when using Spring Autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im trying to learn Spring but Im having a little trouble using the `@Autowired` annotation. When I try to run the example below im getting an nullpoint error on `classA.hello();`line and im not sure why. Any hwlp would be appreciated.

ClassATest

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ContextConfigurationClass.class})
public class ClassATest {

    @Autowired
    ClassA classA;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        classA.hello();
    }
    }
```

ClassA

```
package com;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ClassA {

    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}
```

Context Configuration

```
package com;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com"
})
public class ContextConfigurationClass {

}
```

Comment: You're missing an annotation or a configuration, to make the Autowired working, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage) for more info (or one of the related question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NullPointerException occurs because the test doesn't create a Spring context and therefore doesn't inject ClassA.

To solve this, add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to ClassATest.