# What's the use of @Autowired annotation in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm new to Spring Boot. I have created a demo REST API in Spring Boot. In the following code, even if remove the `@Autowired` annotation, the controller still works and I'm able to call the API.

```
import com.abhishek.demo2.entity.Question;
import com.abhishek.demo2.service.QuestionService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController
{
   QuestionService questionService;

   @Autowired
   public QuestionController(QuestionService questionService)
   {
       this.questionService = questionService;
   }

   @GetMapping("/all")
   public List<Question> getAllQuestions()
   {
       return questionService.getAllQuestions();
   }
}
```

So, now I'm wondering what is the use of this @Autowired annotation, and how it works.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Spring Framework, starting from version 4.3, the @Autowired annotation is no longer required for constructor injection. If your class has only one constructor, Spring Boot automatically injects the dependencies without requiring the @Autowired annotation.

Here's an example to illustrate this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController
{
   QuestionService questionService;
    // No @Autowired annotation is needed here
   // @Autowired
   public QuestionController(QuestionService questionService)
   {
       this.questionService = questionService;
   }

   @GetMapping("/all")
   public List<Question> getAllQuestions()
   {
       return questionService.getAllQuestions();
   }
}
```

In the example above, the `QuestionService` dependency is automatically injected into the `QuestionController` constructor without the need for the @Autowired annotation.

If you have multiple constructors in your class, then you might need to use the @Autowired annotation to indicate which constructor Spring should use for dependency injection. However, if you have only one constructor, Spring Boot will perform automatic constructor injection without requiring the @Autowired annotation.

#### Best Practise

Typically , we build a constructor for dependecny injection , but hard coded a constructor which contains is too heavy and inconvenient for modification in the future ., so you can have a try with `lombok` [doc](https://projectlombok.org/) , it is a lib that would reduce simple and complicated code like getter and setter or builder and other basic data operation with entity class.

In a netshell, you can simpify code like below

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/question")
//  add annotation which would build constructor with field type final 
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QuestionController
{
   private final QuestionService questionService;


   @GetMapping("/all")
   public List<Question> getAllQuestions()
   {
       return questionService.getAllQuestions();
   }
}
```

lombok  dependency is following

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>  // replace other version is fine , it according to your java version
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Okay, I get it now, but what is the coding convention for this? If there is only one constructor, should we still use the @Autowired annotation or is it okay to not use it?

Comment: demonstrate the most usage that i used to do , you can follow this .

Comment: "In recent versions of Spring Boot, starting from version 4.3" should instead be "In recent versions of Spring _Framework_, starting from version 4.3". Spring Boot and Spring Framework have separate versions, and there is no Spring Boot 4.3 yet.

Comment: @ScottFrederick  yeah  i ' ll fix it

Answer (score 0):

Following is the **NOTE** from spring website - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired.html

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, an `@Autowired` annotation on such a
> constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean defines only one
> constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are
> available and there is no primary/default constructor, at least one of
> the constructors must be annotated with `@Autowired` in order to
> instruct the container which one to use. See the discussion on
> [constructor resolution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired.html#beans-autowired-annotation-constructor-resolution) for details.